# Get username specified in URL from NettyRequest

Tags: netty

I have a Netty HTTP server, and am getting in requests that look like so:

https://someuser%40abc.com@server99.route1.abc.com/rest/of/path.xml

And waaay down in my handler, I have a DefaultHttpRequest object. Is there any way to get the 'someuser%40abc.com' from the URL? Do I have to hack something up to get it earlier and pass it down?

Comment: does HTTP support this kind of URI Scheme? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme says that, HTTP supports generic syntax of URI Scheme which you have given. When I connect to http://someuser@localhost:8080/rest/path using a browser/ wget,  username part does not appear in Wireshark captured HTTP request.

Comment: Shit. You're right. I look at the client logs and it shows that URL, but snoop says that it's not going across the wire :/. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Interesting side note: Curl will add an authorization header if you include both the username and password in the url, but will completely discard it if you just use the username. Safari strips it off and throws it away, as does my client when it opens the http connection :/

Comment: If you want the points, you need to add an answer!

Comment: Thanks @Kylar, I am glad that my comment helped to find the issue,  I was not sure about the wired URI scheme in common and wondering it could be used with some other http services. Now posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 'user' part was missing in DefaultHttpRequest in Netty, I did try to debug the Nety HttpDecoder using sample Netty Snoop server :). When I connect to `http://someuser@localhost:8080/rest/path` using Chrome/ wget, the HttpDecoder didn't receive someuser part as a header to decode, so I checked further by taking a Wireshark captured HTTP request and that also didn't have someuser part as a header.

The reason is, HTTP clients support generic syntax of URI Scheme mostly, and they strip of user part and does not include as headers most of the time.(check Nadeem Douba's answer for more details). If http client can send these parameters as user managed headers, they can be accessed using request.getHeader("X-user-header").

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to ask how to get the URL from messageReceived()?

```
public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    Object msg = e.getMessage();

    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        // New request so let's figure our the service to call
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) msg;

        String uri = request.getUri();

        // Use some string functions to extract what you want for the URI
        String username = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("@")).substring(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. My msg is of the type DefaultHttpRequest, and getUri() returns just the uri portion: /rest/of/path.

Comment: To get the domain name, try getting the "Host" http header.  Something like `request.getHeader("Host")`

Comment: Yeah... I tried that too. It gets stripped off the host header. Stop guessing.

Answer (score 0):

As Jestan Nirojan mentioned earlier, the URI scheme is only supported by the client. The HTTP server will never get a request for `http://user@host`. Also, when using authentication credentials in the URI scheme, the client will only transmit these credentials if it is challenged for them. To clarify, the first request will try to get the page without the user credentials, if the server requires them it will challenge the client, finally the client will repeat the request with the credentials. Otherwise, if the client is not challenged, the page will be served and no credentials will be transmitted as a result.